# Why can't i see my whole tab bar when i add it in a view as subview?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, cgrect

I am new to iPhone development. I am working with an navigational based application and want to add a tab bar view in my application. For that i created a view called TabBarView and added a UITabBarController outlet. viewDidLoad of my TabBarViewController.m is like this:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];
[super viewDidLoad];
 }
```

When i watch it in simulator, i can't see my whole tab bar. I can just see half of it. I went through some tutorials and tried to set view size, but i couldn't. Can anyone tell me why can't i see whole tab bar and how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure that the size of view is 480 cause you see half of it because you have status bar of 20 so your view is 460 please

Your view without statusbar is 480 with it 460
so when you add tabbar with 40 pixel so you have to make the view of size 480...
so not to hide the 20 of status bar